# How can I add fractional times in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have large number of dates in this format:

```
dt = as.POSIXct("2004-04-02 12:45:00 UTC")
```

And I have to add/subtract numbers that may not always be whole numbers.I am using lubridate library.

Example:

```
 dt - days(2)
[1] "2004-03-31 12:45:00 UTC"
```

But,

```
dt - days(1.5)
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “Period” object: periods must have integer values
```

Is there an alternative for this operation?

Comment: Good question. If only R had other date/time functions besides lubridate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is occurring with `days(1.5)`, which doesn't allow fractional periods. You could do:

```
dt - days(1) - hours(12)
```

or

```
dt - 1.5*24*3600
```

or there's probably a base date function that guys like @DirkEddelbuettel know about that would work also. Ah, it's `difftime` (I don't work with dates enough to remember these things off the top of my head).

```
dt - as.difftime(1.5, units="days")
```

And, as pointed out by @maximusdooku:

```
dt - ddays(1.5)
```

(Based on the code, it looks like `ddays` just returns the number of seconds in the requested time period, plus some class information.)

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered ddays and dminutes. dt - ddays(1.5)